# Extract all the sequences from a fasta file with nucleotide A in position 10

Tags: unix, fasta

I am trying to extract all the sequences from a faster file that have an A in position 10. Thats my only requirement. I have found quite a lot of answers but unfortunately people have been looking for the same in position1 not 10. 
So they proposed code won't work for me. Any suggestion?

```
grep '^A' -B 1 file.fa | sed '/--/d' > new_file.fa

cat input.fa |paste - - | awk  '($2 ~ /^A/)' | tr "\t" "\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those solutions looks like only consider a very special case of fasta file, where each sequence is contained only in one line. But if they work for your files in extracting the sequences with an A at the beginning, you only have to modify that regular expression to look for the tenth position:

```
grep '^.........A' --no-group-separator -B 1 file.fa > new_file.fa

<input.fa paste - - | awk  '$2 ~ /^.........A/ {printf("%s\n%s\n", $1, $2)}'
```